# Microsoft ML server /R client package issue

Tags: r, microsoft-r, revoscaler

I have microsoft ML server/ R Client installed in my system. But when I try to load packages, it is giving version errors like the following :

```
namespace ‘stringi’ 1.1.6 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.7 is required
namespace ‘Rcpp’ 0.12.14 is already loaded, but >= 0.12.16 is required
```

This issue exists in a lot of packages. So I tried looking at the repository.

```
 getOption("repos") 

 CRAN   "https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01" 
 CRANextra  "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"
```

And I tried downloading only from the 1st link but still, it is downloading the old version only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using R Open, you are using checkpoint?

Checkpoint freezes your mran repository to a specific snapshot in time. it looks like your mran is frozen to 2018-01-01

```
https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01
```

change the check point to today and update_packages()

```
update_packages()
```

NOTE: this only works from packages that are installed from mran, if you install a package using devtools::install_github() the package will not come from the snapshot.

More info on this

https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility

Look at the FAQ for the following questions.

Why can't I update to or install the latest CRAN packages?

Can I change the default repository for Microsoft R Open?

https://mran.microsoft.com/faq#static-repos

install.packages() [recommends that you always run updated_packages() before installing a new package to ensure that the latest are installed.](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html)

Try the following: (or read the faq to change your repository permanently)

```
checkpoint("2018/09/03")
update_packages()
```

Comment: But it should work if I download all package from same snapshot period right? Im not using any checkpoint but getOption("repos")  gives :

 CRAN   "https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01" . So Im asking why does it matter since I'm downloading all from same date

Comment: What package are you trying to load? Checkpoint only works for mran packages, if you installed a package directly from github it will not be supported.

Comment: I did not download anything from Github

Comment: Default repository is mran. Do you know how to remove all R packages at once, so I can reinstall them?

Comment: I changed the checkpoint to 2018-09-01 but its still showing as 2018-01-01 in getOption("repos")